How NSwag handles anyOf
I have a .net class library which uses NSwag to generate client code from an OpenApi spec, a portion of which is as follows:
"postal_code": {
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "type": "null"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Postal Code"
},

...and when the client code is generated it produces the following type
public partial class Postal_code
{

    private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties;

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
    public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
    {
        get { return _additionalProperties ?? (_additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>()); }
        set { _additionalProperties = value; }
    }

}

Which is not what I want, I just want Postal_Code to be represented as a nullable string.
My current config is as below, is there an option I can add to achieve what I'm looking for?
<ItemGroup>
  <OpenApiReference Include="OpenApis\OpenApiSpec.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" Options="/ClientClassAccessModifier:internal" ClassName="NSwagGeneratedClient" />
</ItemGroup>

Editted to add:
The spec is generated from a python end point using poetry ie poetry run gen-openapi and the Python types which are generating the anyOf  are for example occuption: string | None

Do you use OpenAPI 3.1 or 3.0? If you replace "anyOf": [...] with "type": ["string", "null"], does it make a difference?

3.1.0. When I make the change you suggest then it does generate a string but not a nullable string. The spec was produced using poetry from a python endpoint, might there be options when generating the spec in poetry which alter the spec

@Helen, type as an array is invalid OAS 3.0.x
this sounds like an issue with NSwag and how they determine the types from the schema. I suggest raising it to their repo for further help.  You might try setting the config to "generateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable": true

@JeremyFiel type as an array is valid in OAS 3.1, which is the version the OP uses. (Just clarifying this for future readers.)

i know it's valid in 3.1.x, but you mentioned 3.0 or 3.1.  I know you know this, but maybe it was a typo. I was clarifying it for the OP
